# Firebase get wrong data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a chat app and using firebase as a backend service. I use `snapshot.exists()` to check if a child is exists and do stuff. But Firebase return `true` even that child is not exist. Example : I have 2 users A and B, user A send a message to user B , when user B received that message and check if the message is exist, ofcourse Firebase return `true`. Then user B closes the app and user A delete the message on database, user B restart app and check again, but it still return `true` even user A deleted the message.

P/s : I am using Persistance mode

this the the Database struture

```
----Messages
    |---UserA
    |------UserB
    |---------MessageId
    |---UserB
    |------UserA
    |---------MessageId
```

code to check exist (run on user B device )

```
             ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).orderByKey().equalTo(messageId)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    //do stuff
                }else {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

UPDATE

I change the code to

```
ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).child(messageId)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {});
```

but it still has the data even I deleted it from database

UPDATE 2

also tried this code but it still return data and snapshot still exists

```
ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).child(messageId).keepSynced(true);

ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).child(messageId)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

//after do stuff 

ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).child(messageId).keepSynced(false);

});
```

**FOR NOW I AM STILL GETTING STUCK , BUT I AM USING A TEMP SOLUTION THAT DOUBLE THE QUERY, THE FIRST QUERY WILL BE UNUSABLE, WE WILL GET THE DATA FROMM THE SECOND ONE QUERY**

```
ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).child(messageId)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

// dont use the first one

 ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).child(messageId)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
//get data from the second one
});

});
```

**FINAL UPDATE:
May be it is not posible if I want to check data on someone else node in my app with that database structure. To make it, I need to attach `keepsynced` or add a listener on `Messsages` node and cached the lasted data, this is not convenient for almost app at all.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190268/firebase-always-true-when-checking-if-data-exists

Comment: Note that `.orderByKey().equalTo(messageId)` is the same as `.child(messageId)`, except for the format in which the data is returned.

Comment: Aside from that: `addListenerForSingleValueEvent ` and disk persistence don't work well together. Using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will immediately return the value from the cache. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487195

Comment: I used `KeepSynced` on the current user database node, not on the other users node. How can I check that child exist on the some users else node

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that when UserA deletes the `messageId` message from the server, that both users copies of the message (`Messages/UserA/UserB/messageId` and `Messages/UserB/UserA/messageId`) are deleted.

In your question's code, you are performing a query, rather than a simple database lookup. When you use any of the `orderBy` functions, you will always get a snapshot object back that 'exists', but you must look at that returned snapshot's children because that's where the query's results are stored.

[Documentation on working with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

To summarize, to go through the results of a query,

- Use [`snapshot.hasChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#hasChildren()) to check for any results,
- Use [`snapshot.getChildrenCount()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount()) to count the number of results, and
- Use [`snapshot.getChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getChildren()) to go through the results using an iterator.

In your case, this problem can be avoided (and optimized) by not using `orderByKey()` on this line:

```
ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).orderByKey().equalTo(messageId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

and simplifying it to a basic database lookup where `snapshot.exists()` would work as you expect in your question:

```
ROOT_REF.child("Messages").child("UserA").child(userB_Id).child(messageId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

Comment: see my update please